# Assigning values based on fractions of data

Tags: r

So I have a really large dataset that has some missing/bad data. I would like to code the missing data using an IF else statement. Instead of assigning just one value for all of the missing/bad ones, I want to assign base on a fraction.

So for instance for df below:

Assign 50% of the `df$col2==B` to BLUE and the other 50% to RED

```
col1  col2
1     a
2     a
3     b
4     b
```

I know you can do:

```
if else( df$col2==b, "BLUE", df$col1)
```

but I want:

```
 col1  col2
1     a
2     a
3     BLUE
4     RED
```

I'm looking to do the partitioning base of the condition.

Comment: Adding a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) may make it easier for the StackOverflow community to help find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by generating a vector of "Red" and "Blue" to select as the replacement when needed.

```
## Generate some random data with missing values
set.seed(2017)
a = sample(c("Red", "Blue"), 20, replace=TRUE)
a = ifelse(runif(20, 0, 1) < 0.12, NA, a)

## Now replace missing
a = ifelse(is.na(a), 
          sample(c("Red", "Blue"), length(a), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5,0.5)), a)
```